toSignal on observables inside signal
With the recent Angular update (we are using v. 17) we started to use Angular signals in our application. There is one problem we are stumpling accross, that we are not sure how to handle properly.
We have components that receive a FormControl as @Input. We adjusted the code to the new Input-Signals
public readonly control = input<FormControl | null>(null)

Now we would like to have the valueChanges or statusChanges available as a signal, but we don't know how.
This is not reactive:
public readonly value = toSignal(this.control().valueChanges);

This is not allowed:
public readonly value = computed(() => toSignal(this.control().valueChanges));

Having the value as a signal could help to use it in more complex computed ways. E.g.
public readonly complexCondition = computed(() =>  this.value() == // some complex checks

and then use the signal in the template.
Without that, we would need a getter or a method which would not work with OnPush-Strategy (I think?) or would be executed every cycle, causing unnecessary calls because values might just stay the same.
Setting the signal manually from an effect is also prevented. We could put it into an effect which sets a basic variable maybe like this:
effect(() => {
    this.control()?.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.complexCondition =  this.value() == // some complex checks
    })

});

but that does seem a bit hacky and I think also would not work with OnPush-Strategy
Question:
How to structure such cases?
I tried to find anything in the Angular docs or blogs, but I could find a similar problem. I think I might be on the wrong track here, but looking forward to see the proper way to do this.
EDIT
I continued reading into the topic and I think what actually would solve my problem is that Angular forms provide signals. Or we would have to wrap the formControl in our own class and provide own signal logic, but without the use of toSignal (handy for valueChanges and statusChanges) since this cannot be used outside of injection contexts.
There is this open feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53485
As far as I read, this is something the Angular team is working on. Until then one could use this package: https://github.com/timdeschryver/ng-signal-forms
This is not an option for us, cause switching to this package would mean a lot of changes. But maybe it helps somebody else.

But why do you use reactive form with Input ? A good practice is to have the formControl in a Formgroup. The form builder help to do that and have form strictly typed too. You just have to subscribe valueChange to "react" change by using declarative approach

We need a true example to help, with context. To much bad things here

FormControl was just an example here. You could swap that with any type that has a field of type Observable. I updated my question. The first answer I got actually solves this issue even though being a bit of code to write. I would not have stumbled across the problem when the object passed as SignalInput had properties of type signal.

Key Considerations:

The value of control will change and the child should be adapted to update of control state
There will always be a form control defined, if you still want to use null as initial value, then the @if is necessary, else you can discard that if condition in the html

The control is a input property so it can be updated in the future, so need to take this into account.

Since the signal input change I use effect to validate when the control gets updated

Then I subscribe to the signal control's valueChanges observable, but make sure to store it in an subscription object, why I do this is because when the control changes, the previous value changes subscription is useless, so we need to clean it up, I use a if condition and an unsubscribe.

When the value changes of the control I create a new signal to store the control value and set the value inside the value changes

Finally, I add a cleanup block, since subscriptions should not live after the component is destroyed.

Since we are setting the value of a signal in the effect, I use allowSignalWrites: true to allow this to be done!

I use a computed signal to perform any complex calculations needed, here it's just a toggle of label (valueFromComplexCondition)


Full Code
Child
import { Component, input, effect, computed, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  @if(control(); as controlObj) {
    <input [formControl]="controlObj"/>
    <br/>
    valueFromComplexCondition: {{valueFromComplexCondition()}}
  }
  `,
  styleUrl: './test.component.css',
})
export class TestComponent {
  public readonly control = input<FormControl>(new FormControl());
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  valueFromComplexCondition = computed(() =>
    this.value() === 'hello!' ? 'Correct' : 'incorrect'
  );
  private value = signal(this.control().value);

  constructor() {
    effect(
      (onCleanup: Function) => {
        if (this.subscription) {
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        const control = this.control();
        if (control) {
          this.value.set(control.value);
          this.subscription = control.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
            console.log(val);
            this.value.set(val);
          });
        }

        onCleanup(() => {
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
      },
      {
        allowSignalWrites: true,
      }
    );
  }
}

Parent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestComponent } from './app/test/test.component';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TestComponent],
  template: `
  
    <app-test [control]="!switcher ? formControlA : formControlB"/>
    <button (click)="switcher = !switcher">toggle controls {{switcher ? "formControlB" : "formControlA"}}</button>
    <br/>
    formControlA: {{formControlA.value}}
    <br/>
    formControlB: {{formControlB.value}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  switcher = false;
  formControlA = new FormControl('hello!');
  formControlB = new FormControl('hello world!');
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for your quick reply. This what I was thinking of, but I was unsure if allowSignalWrites is considered bad practice? Also this is quite a bit of code that would be needed for each observable if there are more than one. is this the offical recommended approach or do you have any references? :)

@Julia It is large because it is designed to handle input signal change( even if you change the form control the code will work! ), if we are dealing with static input, it will be smaller, but do wait for a better answer from someone more knowledgeable on signals!

I thought about my problem and your solution again and accepted it, since it actually solves the problem even when it is a bit of code. Thanks for your input. :)

Without using the effect function,
I think you could use the combination of toSignal and toObservable like this:
  public control: InputSignal<FormControl<T>> = input<FormControl<T>>();
  public readonly value: Signal<T> = toSignal(
    merge(
      // Get the initial value when 'control' changes
      toObservable(this.control).pipe(map((ctl: FormControl<T>) => ctl.value)),
      // Get the new value when 'control.value' changes
      toObservable(this.control).pipe(mergeMap((ctl: FormControl<T>) => ctl.valueChanges))
    )
  );

You could define a utility function to do this.
class SignalTransformerUtils {
  public static fromControlToValue = <T>(controlSignal: Signal<FormControl<T>>): Signal<T> => {
    return toSignal(
      merge(
        // Get the initial value when 'control' changes
        toObservable(controlSignal).pipe(map((ctl: FormControl<T>) => ctl.value)),
        // Get the new value when 'control.value' changes
        toObservable(controlSignal).pipe(mergeMap((ctl: FormControl<T>) => ctl.valueChanges))
      )
    );
  };
}

// ...

  public control: InputSignal<FormControl<T>> = input<FormControl<T>>();
  public readonly value: Signal<T> = SignalTransformerUtil.fromControlToValue(this.control);



I like the solution but encountered an issue with formGroup. The initial value of formGroup is undefined, so I can't access nested properties in HTML.
The workaround in my case was  return computed(() => signal() ?? control().value); where the signal is original toSignal from the answer.

regarding the specific problem of extracting value from a FormControl, I've written a reusable function based on Naren Murali's answer, which you can use on variable initialization. It uses getRawValue(), so both FormControls and FormGroups can be passed as arguments.
The function:
const computedFromControl = <T, S = T>(
    control: () => { getRawValue(): T; valueChanges: Observable<unknown> },
    computation = (value: T) => value as unknown as S,
): Signal<S> => {
    let valueChangesSubscription: Subscription | undefined

    const value = signal<T | null>(null)

    effect(
        onCleanup => {
            valueChangesSubscription?.unsubscribe()

            value.set(control().getRawValue())
            valueChangesSubscription = control().valueChanges.subscribe(() => value.set(control().getRawValue()))

            onCleanup(() => valueChangesSubscription?.unsubscribe())
        },
        { allowSignalWrites: true },
    )

    return computed(() => computation(value() ?? control().getRawValue()))
}

Usage:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    template: `<div>{{ complexCondition() }}</div>`,
})
export class AppTestComponent {
    public readonly control = input.required<FormControl<boolean>>()

    public readonly complexCondition = computedFromControl(
        this.control,
        value => value ? 'value is true' : 'value is false',
    )
}

